# storm-kafka-client:1.2.2 KafkaSpoutConfig using Yaml

Tags: java, apache-kafka, yaml, apache-storm

I am trying to configure the KafkaSpout through YAML and I am getting the below error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Below is a bit from my YAML file

```
name: "SampleTopology"

components:
- id: "onlyValueRecordTranslator"
className: "org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.DefaultRecordTranslator"

- id: "spoutConfigBuilder"
  className: 
 "org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpoutConfig$Builder"
  constructorArgs:
  - "localhost:9092"
  - ["myKafkaTopic"]
  properties:
  - name: "firstPollOffsetStrategy"
    value: "LATEST"
  - name: "recordTranslator"
    ref: "onlyValueRecordTranslator"
 configMethods:
  - name: "setProp"
    args:
      - {
        "key.deserializer" : 
  "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
        "value.deserializer": 
  "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"
      }


  - id: "spoutConfig"
  className: "org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpoutConfig"
  constructorArgs:
  - ref: "spoutConfigBuilder"
```

Can someone please point me to any examples of how to use KafkaSpoutConfig though YAML?

I am using the below versions of storm and kafka

```
org.apache.storm:storm-core:1.2.2
org.apache.storm:storm-kafka-client:1.2.2
org.apache.storm', name: 'flux-core', version: '1.2.2
```

Comment: At least https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator says the included yaml is not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The YAML looks right (going to assume the broken indentation is a copy-paste error, otherwise you need to fix that).

You are affected by the bug fixed in https://github.com/apache/storm/pull/2575. It has only been fixed in Storm 2.0.0, not in the 1.x branches. I don't see a reason we couldn't backport it.

The code you want backported is this file https://github.com/apache/storm/pull/2575/files#diff-472112e23a03ec30ae9c55beab542631. Feel free to open an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira for it. If you want to work on it, you can submit the PR to https://github.com/apache/storm/pull.